# Dataframe transformation with nested objects

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a json object with stores has a column storing data as

```json
"geoLocation": [{"double": -95.39510349999999, "int": null}, {"double": 29.70816599999999, "int": null}]
```

I would like to convert this to

```json
"geoLocation": ["double": -95.39510349999999, "double": 29.70816599999999]
```

How to go about doing it without going through each line one-by-one.

Thanks in advance

Have tried using cast operations, and other options. But was not able to find the solution.